# Reversal badge not available on Super User

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I've just noticed that the Reversal badge isn't available on [Super User](https://superuser.com/badges).

Is this an oversight or by design?

It's available on both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/badges)

**7<sup>th</sup> November 2009**

Still not turned on.

**7<sup>th</sup> December 2009**

The Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges were rolled out across all the sites, but the Reversal badge is still not appearing.

Comment: Looks like it just hasn't been turned on yet.

Comment: closed by owner's request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented (some time ago now).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they don't want to encourage people to post on low voted questions on SuperUser? After all, the average quality of questions there is regrettably lower.

Comment: Would be nice to know for certain. Maybe a mod could add a [status-bydesign] tag to the question.